# How to write SQL query in Java to get data from Snowflake

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to write this Snowflake query into Java code:

```
copy into s3://snowflake171
  from USER_TABLE
  storage_integration = s3_int
  file_format = CSV_TEST;
```

I am writing it like this:

```
 String q ="COPY INTO s3://snowflake171\n" +
                    "  FROM \"TEST\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER_TABLE\"WHERE\"ID\\\"=?\"\n" +
                    "  storage_integration = s3_int\n" +
                    "  file_format = CSV_TEST";
```

But I am getting this error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [COPY INTO s3://snowflake171
  FROM "TEST"."PUBLIC"."USER_TABLE"WHERE"ID\"=?"
  storage_integration = s3_int
  file_format = CSV_TEST]; nested exception is net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 5 unexpected '<EOF>'.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: "unexpected 'INOT" - it seems you're not sending `INTO` but `INOT`. Please check your code.

Comment: Sorry I updated it was not that :(

Comment: `WHERE"ID\"=?"` - you're missing the parameter here. Also, the query seems to miss the semi-colon at the end: I'd say it should be `"  file_format = CSV_TEST;";`

Comment: I have fixed parameter now I HAVE THIS ERROR: `SQL access control error:
Insufficient privileges to operate on integration 'S3_INT'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the latest error message is "SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on integration 'S3_INT'", can you try to grant USAGE permission on s3_int to your role? Are you sure you set the correct role when connecting?

```
String url = "jdbc:snowflake://<account_identifier>.snowflakecomputing.com";
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("user", "<user>");
prop.put("privateKey", PrivateKeyReader.get(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE));
prop.put("db", "<database_name>");
prop.put("schema", "<schema_name>");
prop.put("warehouse", "<warehouse_name>");
prop.put("role", "<role_name>");
```

Comment: Thank you that was it! There is also possibility to put it in `url` like this: `jdbc:snowflake://account.aws.snowflakecomputing.com/?db=TEST&warehouse=SF_TUTS_WH&schema=PUBLIC&role=ACCOUNTADMIN`